# Function with returns compiles without return statement

Tags: solidity, remix

I was surprised to find out that the `returns` clause in function declaration seems not to be enforced. That is, the following code compiles in browser-solidity (`foo` returns `0` when invoked):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract TestContract {
    function foo() returns (uint) {
        uint b = 3+5;
        //return b;
    }
}
```

Isn't it supposed not to type-check if the function that is declared to return something in fact does not? What is the rationale behind this design decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "return x" is equivalent to "r = x; return;" where r is the return variable. As all variables are automatically assigned a "zero value" (including the return variables), not using "return" is not unsafe but it might indicate a programming error.

Especially if you name the return variables, code that does not use an explicit "return" is sometimes easier to read and check.

Comment: So am I correct that a function with `returns (uint)` in its declaration implicitly produces a return variable with some hidden name and returns it in all cases I forget to write `return`? It just seems kinda strange that the following two situations are handled differently: 1) function with `returns (uint)` returns `true` - type error, does not compile; 2) described above - compiles. Aren't both cases examples of functions breaking the predefined "calling contract"?